# Blender stops responding when i try to add rigidbody constraints

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

So i just used cell fracture to make 500 shards, and when i add a constraint (left panel under physics, constraint: connect button) it stops responding. Ive left it over night and am losing hope that it will come back. What should i do? Will it come back if i leave it? Task Manager says it is using ~600 mb of ram.

Comment: hard to say, also I cannot understand completely your constraint setup... it could need to test with smaller objects/shards...

Comment: So I used a high vertacies apartment building. Took awhile to make the shards, and this morning I just quit the program because I lost hope. The method works with less high vertacies objects and the same shard count so it's weird.